# Sorted table without a duplicates

Tags: xml, xslt

Good morning,

I have a XML file that has the following structure:

```
<Reports>
    <UUTs>
        <Results>
        <SerialNumberToSearch></SerialNumberToSearch>
            <Result ID="0">
                <SerialNumber>1234</SerialNumber>
                <Status>Fail</Status>
                <Date>2021-03-05T08:15:21</Date>
            </Result>
            <Result ID="1">
                <SerialNumber>1234</SerialNumber>
                <Status>Fail</Status>
                <Date>2021-03-05T08:23:23</Date>
            </Result>
            <Result ID="2">
                <SerialNumber>1234</SerialNumber>
                <Status>Fail</Status>
                <Date>2021-03-05T08:16:23</Date>
            </Result>
            <Result ID="3">
                <SerialNumber>6556175708</SerialNumber>
                <Status>Pass</Status>
                <Date>2021-03-05T09:15:21</Date>
            </Result>
            <Result ID="4">
                <SerialNumber>1234</SerialNumber>
                <Status>Pass</Status>
                <Date>2021-03-05T08:17:21</Date>
            </Result>
            <Result ID="5">
                <SerialNumber>11908817202</SerialNumber>
                <Status>Pass</Status>
                <Date>2021-03-05T07:11:21</Date>
            </Result>
            <Result ID="6">
                <SerialNumber>2406339084</SerialNumber>
                <Status>Pass</Status>
                <Date>2021-03-05T08:15:21</Date>
            </Result>
        </Results>
    </UUTs>
</Reports>
```

I would like to transform this XML into the table that is sorted by Date and there is no SerialNumber duplicates. That is what i have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>


<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="UUTs/Results">
    <fo:block >
        <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%"> 
            <fo:table-header>
                <fo:table-row keep-with-next="always" background-color="#EAEAEA">
                    <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="myBorder" padding-left="3mm">
                        <fo:block font-weight="bold" font-family="sans-serif">Serial Number</fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="myBorder" padding-left="3mm">
                        <fo:block font-weight="bold" font-family="sans-serif">Test Result</fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="myBorder" padding-left="3mm">
                        <fo:block font-weight="bold" font-family="sans-serif">Date</fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="myBorder" padding-left="3mm">
                        <fo:block font-weight="bold" font-family="sans-serif">Time</fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
            </fo:table-header>
            
            <fo:table-body>
            <xsl:for-each select="Result">
                <xsl:sort select="./Date" order="descending"/>

                    <fo:table-row>
                        
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="myBorder" padding-left="3mm">
                            <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="./SerialNumber"/></fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="myBorder" padding-left="3mm">
                            <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="./Status"/></fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="myBorder" padding-left="3mm">
                            <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="substring(./Date,0,11)"/></fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="myBorder" padding-left="3mm">
                            <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="substring(./Date,12,8)"/></fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        
                        
                    </fo:table-row>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </fo:table-body>    
        </fo:table>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the output in the table that I am looking for:

| **Serial Number** | **Test Result** | **Date** | **Time** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6556175708 | Pass | 2021-03-05 | 09:15:21 |
| 1234 | Fail | 2021-03-05 | 08:23:23 |
| 11908817202 | Pass | 2021-03-05 | 07:11:21 |
| 2406339084 | Pass | 2021-03-05 | 07:11:21 |

I need to remove SerialNumber duplicates somehow now, but I have no idea how could I do that. I tried different solutions, but it failed due to my lack of knowledge.

Comment: Start here: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html -- Note that in your example, all Results with the same SerialNumber also have the same Date and Status. It's not clear whether that will be always so, and if not, what should the result be then.